# Android Studio get emulator name with Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, device

I'm working on an app and would like to know if it's possible with flutter to get the emulator name. 
I tried with [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) but unfortunately, it doesn't return the custom emulator name created in AVD manager, the data that I get is:

```
result = {AndroidDeviceInfo} 
 version = {AndroidBuildVersion} 
  baseOS = ""
  codename = "REL"
  incremental = "4409132"
  previewSdkInt = 0
  release = "7.0"
  sdkInt = 24
  securityPatch = "2017-10-05"
 board = "unknown"
 bootloader = "unknown"
 brand = "google"
 device = "generic_x86"
 display = "NYC"
 fingerprint = "google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.0/NYC/4409132:user/release-keys"
 hardware = "ranchu"
 host = "wphr6.hot.corp.google.com"
 id = "NYC"
 manufacturer = "Google"
 model = "Android SDK built for x86"
 product = "sdk_google_phone_x86"
 supported32BitAbis = {_ImmutableList} size = 1
 supported64BitAbis = {_ImmutableList} size = 0
 supportedAbis = {_ImmutableList} size = 1
 tags = "release-keys"
 type = "user"
 isPhysicalDevice = false
 androidId = "b5ca8578c2af3a7d"
```

I'm looking to get this name.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you want the emulator name?

Comment: @Er1 just by curiosity and was thinking to have some custom code while using certain emulator names. It could be done by running with a different configuration in *main* file or a different *flavour*, but just wanted to know if it's possible to take the device name, didn't find an answer elsewhere.